# Ocultar el area azul de los enlaces de una web al pulsarlos desde la vista de smartphone

Tags: css

Mi problema consiste en que quiero que en mi web, cuando navegas desde la vista de smartphone o tablet, no aparezca el area azul en los links al pulsarlos. Cuando se pulsa en un enlace, éste se rellena de un color azul indicando que es un enlace.

He probado con outline pero no ha funcionado.

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Buenas! sería recomendable poner algun ejemplo. Asi sabremos de que trata tu problema con exactitud. ¿Has probado con "text-decoration"? De todas formas, echale un vistazo a [ask]

Comment: puedes agregar un ejemplo miimo de lo que haz hecho?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con **a:link** que permite enfocarse en los enlaces de hipertexto **href** y no en los atributos **name** por ejemplo

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Con **text-decoration** quitas el típico subrayado de los enlaces pero te seguirá saliendo del mismo color, el cual tendrás también que cambiarlo

Puedes luego jugar tambien con pseudo-clases como **a:visited** para los ya visitados